GitLab Runner Cache and Linter Issues with Concurrent 6 Setting
I've set up a new build machine and I'm configuring GitLab Runner. I've followed the setup instructions and haven't changed anything in the config.toml file except for setting concurrent = 6. However, I'm encountering cache issues and the linter fails.
Has anyone else faced these problems or have tips on resolving them? Any advice on configuring the cache properly or ensuring the linter works with multiple concurrent jobs would be appreciated.
Thank you!
I tried setting up a cache server, but I ran into problems with that as well. I simply want the cache to be shared between jobs and for the Runner to handle multiple jobs concurrently.
